# Nightwatch setValue not entering value correctly in textBox

Tags: nightwatch.js, setvalue

I am new to nightwatch and was trying to create sample project.I am using following code to enter value in text Box
browser
      .url('https://www.google.com.au/')
      .setValue('input[type=text]', 'YRZF2V4KB223333')

But when I checked Chrome window value entered in 
YRZF2V4KB22

I  tried changing text to 
browser
      .url('https://www.google.com.au/')
      .setValue('input[type=text]', 'YRZF32V4KB22')

But again value entered in Google search was YRZF2V4KB22

I noticed value '3' is not getting entered in text Box, please let me know if I am missing anything.

Browser : Chrome

Comment: I have the same issue with password 3 is getting missed, if I pause and place it manually. It works as usual. Also new to this shit.

Comment: Copied pasted your code as of 2021-11-04 and it works as expected:

https://cln.sh/dZfGs4